# internal create-md' terminated with exit code 20 - DRBD

Tags: high-availability, partition, disk, pacemaker, drbd

I am doing database replication with DRBD. Using different ips for pacemaker, corosync & Drbd traffic.Created one partition (vdc1). I am not able to setup DRBD. It's giving below error-

**Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/vdc1 internal create-md' terminated with exit code 20**

I am not getting what's the issue. Help me in resolving this issue

```
$ sudo drbdadm create-md clusterdb
read from drbdsetup
: Success
read from drbdsetup
: Success
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/vdc1 internal create-md' terminated with exit code 20
```

/etc/hosts -

```
172.0.3.30 app3_pcmk
172.0.3.40 app4_pcmk
172.0.5.30 app3_drbd
172.0.5.30 app4_drbd
172.0.3.9 app4
172.0.3.8 app3
```

/etc/drbd.d/clusterdb.res

```
resource clusterdb
{
protocol C;
startup {
wfc-timeout 30;
outdated-wfc-timeout 20;
degr-wfc-timeout 30;
}
net {
cram-hmac-alg sha1;
shared-secret sync_disk;
after-sb-0pri discard-zero-changes;
after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
after-sb-2pri disconnect;
}
syncer {
rate 10M;
al-extents 257;
on-no-data-accessible io-error;
}
on app3 {
device /dev/drbd0;
disk /dev/vdc1;
address 172.0.3.8:7788;
flexible-meta-disk internal;
}
on app4 {
device /dev/drbd0;
disk /dev/vdc1;
address 172.0.3.9:7788;
meta-disk internal;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: What versions of DRBD and the DRBD Utils are you using? `drbdadm --version`